# Elegant way to check data from a form

Tags: python, pyqt

I think this is a general question, however, in my case I'm working with PyQt5 and Python 3.

I'm setting up a small software, which is recording data with a measurement device. Before a measurement I have to put some data which are then validated by the software for correctness, like, is a mandatory field filled, or is the input value within the allowed range, or i.e., I have a start value `A`, a stop value `B` and a step width `W`, so I have to validate if `W<=B-A`

My question is, what's the most elegant way of checking the form? I can just simply do it one by one:

```
class Form:
    ...

    def check_form(self):
        if self.fieldA.text() == "":
            return False

        if not self.check_range(self.fieldB.text()):
            return False

        # Check fields one by one...
        ...

    def check_range(self, val):
        if val > self.max_val:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

But actually, this isn't really pretty, it's repeating code and a lot to write and hard to maintain. So my question is, is there a better way? One idea which came up was to define a object (maybe a dict), which contains all relevant form information, like label, default value, conditions and so on... I can put that form into a json file and then just load it and even generate the form when I need it. Maybe some obstacles may occur, especially I have to think how to handle drop down lists, but I think this is at least one approach.

Anyway. 100% someone else were struggling with this issue before me, so maybe there's a standard way how to solve this in an elegant way.

Answer (score -1):

A good UX practice is to inform user the expectation of the software instead of making them guess, possiblly enter incorrect value and then informed/misinformed with cryptic error message that they don't understand!

In the situation you described here, clearly indicate an asterisk(*) next to input label to indicate it is a mandatory field. Possibly software should also come up with sensible default value. Also using correct widget to solve the particular problem you've described here would be a good idea. So instead of having three QLineEdit fields that take numerical inputs as text fields, I'd just use QSpinBox or QDoubleSpinBox that are designed to request a well constraint range of values.

Comment: Sorry, my question was about how to check the data of a form, not how to design it.